# The pitfalls of starting a coded bot with SDK v4

Tags: botframework

I'm about to build a chat bot using Microsoft's Bot Framework. I've been transcribing the docs for days to immerse myself in the newness.

It feels like Microsoft wants me to use Composer, but surely Code is King...

I sense that SDK v4 has feature parity with Composer, right?

I can see questions on here about migrating one way or the other. Is this a *one way door*, in Jeff Bezos speak?

What pitfalls can I expect if I go the coded route? Is this really one of those things that's best done with a GUI?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there's no right answer here. My personal opinion is that Composer makes many "core" features so much easier to create, from dialogs to prompts to using bots as skills. However, as soon as you step out from what Composer considers "standard" (e.g. a dialog loop where you want to maintain some prompt values but reprompt others), you either have to compromise on the features or go to coded. Microsoft is definitely pushing Composer, but I have features that, although maybe not completely necessary, cannot easily (or maybe not at all) be implemented with Composer. I have some of my team exploring Composer bots right now, but for new projects we are still using fully coded bots.